# Excel Integration gives 0 for Sum but #Value for adding cells by specifying the value :(

Tags: .net, excel, integration

We performed integration with Excel Document(s) which uses lots of complex formulas and algorithm to calculate thousands of values(some times in a single document).

**Issue 1**: The issue is the use of SUM function which returns 0 instead of calculated value like putting below values in two column and try to use SUM function and Cell1 + Cell2 to understand one of the issues. :(

9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

**Fix 1**:
The solution to the problem is to use column names instead of the Sum function but we are not allowed to change the excel documents (more than one version) because of the fact that these documents are not supposed to be altered.

**Issue 2**:
I believe this is not a dead end but the reported issues are wrong results because of those zeros which someone needs to fix.

**Fix 2 and Issue #3**:
We added a component to capture this scenario by identifying 0 value but 80% of the auto-reported issues have valid scenarios and the 0 result is correct.

**To Be Fix 3**:
Now we have another direction to write some algorithm to identify and filter those 80% auto identified issues by checking the source values which will reduce the number of auto-identified issues and only 20% will show up for manual fix due to some invalid data entry :(

We just want to get some feedback because we believe that after identifying all (80%) valid scenarios, we may face more issues. Even the To Be Fix #3 will require significant effort (Dev/QA) and much more...

**Important**: The number of excel files is in thousands/month but 73 identical templates (There were 15 templates in the beginning but now in couple of years the number of templates has increased). If not part of the 73 standard templates, then someone has to manually fix and reload in the system for processing or a new template is introduced for which a new component is developed and deployed. User doesn't want to leave Excel but back office wants some automatic system to reduce the workload.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's completely unclear to me what you're asking. Perhaps you could try phrasing it differently? Thanks.

Comment: "User doesn't want to leave Excel "  haha that's classic.  sounds like User needs to have a database, not a whole file system of excel files.

Comment: Please re-state issue #1

Comment: SUM returns zero when you pass it strings. If you have a 'number' that's more than 15 digits, it's probably a string.

Comment: To understand Issue # 1, please review the only Answer given below :)

We have tried numerous times to move end user from excel to some  application but the End user (really) doesn't want to leave the power of Excel :(

Even there are more than 40 sheets in some Excel files and more than 10 MB in size.

I just tried to share some history of the project and major encountered issues. The below answer is one of the example to fix the issues which End User is not considering a good idea...

I'm sorry if most of you couldn't understand the issue but I just wanted to share some experience!!!

Answer (score 0):

To get around #value or 'zero' return where not accurate you can check if the statement will throw an error and then flag it with some value that you can now easily separate your 20% failures with.

For example, if A1+A2 with your 999's from above causes #value, try this instead:

```
=IFERROR(A1+A2,"Failed")
```

Now you can easily find all the "Failed" cells and 'update' them.